# Javascript/PHP redirect

Tags: javascript, php, html, http-redirect

Hello fellow programmers!

I'm working on a personal project (mainly to learn php/javascript) and have ran into an issue with redirection when clicking on a link.  I have a bit of a strange situation on a tabbed page I've created and I think that may be what is causing my problem.

I'm trying to allow the user to click the  (which due to css has made it look different than normal ) to redirect them to a new page with more details.  I THINK that the second  tag on my page is what is throwing me off because I have a form in it.

I have tried tons of different things like window.location.href="", location.href="", document.location="", etc...  But the same thing always occurs.  I am able to get both alert messages, so I know I am getting into my JavaScript (even when I put it into it's own .js file).

Anyway advice/help would be very helpful.  Also, if anyone has a suggestion on cleaning this code up a bit, that would also be truly helpful.

Below is basically what I have.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test site</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function viewDetails(modelId){
            alert(modelId);
            window.location.href="new url?ModelID=" + modelId;
            alert('redirecting would be way awesome...');
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">

    <div id="tabbed_box_1" class="tabbed_box">
        <h4>Navigation Tabs<small>Select a tab</small></h4>
        <div class="tabbed_area">
            <?php
            mysql_connect('host','user','password');
            mysql_select_db("database");

            echo "<ul class='tabs'>";
                echo "<li><a href='javascript:tabSwitch(1, 2);' id='tab_1' class='active'>Inventory</a></li>";
                echo "<li><a href='javascript:tabSwitch(2, 2);' id='tab_2' >Add Project</a></li>";
            echo "</ul>";

            echo "<div id='content_1' class='content'>";
                echo "<ul>";
                    $modelsSQL = "SELECT * FROM Model ORDER BY Name";
                    $modelsResult = mysql_query($modelsSQL);
                    while ($modelRow = mysql_fetch_array($modelsResult)){
                        $modelID = $modelRow[0];
                        $sqlAvailCount = "SELECT * FROM Project WHERE ModelID = " . $modelID . " AND Sold = 0";
                        $sqlSoldCount =  "SELECT * FROM Project WHERE ModelID = " . $modelID . " AND Sold = 1";
                        $resultAvailCount = mysql_query($sqlAvailCount);
                        $resultSoldCount = mysql_query($sqlSoldCount);
                        $rowAvailCount = mysql_num_rows($resultAvailCount);
                        $rowSoldCount = mysql_num_rows($resultSoldCount);
                        echo "<li><a href='' onclick='javascript:viewDetails($modelID);'>" . $modelRow[1] . "<small>in stock: <value>" 
                        . $rowAvailCount . "</value> sold: <value>" . $rowSoldCount . "</value></small></a></li>";
                    }
                echo "</ul>";
            echo "</div>";

            echo "<div id='content_2' class='content'>";
                echo "<form action='project_insert.php' method='post' name='projectAddForm'>";
                    echo "<table cellpadding='5'>";

                        // Project Model Selection
                        echo "<tr><td>";
                            echo "<label for='model'>Model</label>";
                        echo "</td><td>";
                            echo "<select name='model' style='width: 250px;'>";
                            echo "<option value='-1' selected>SELECT</option>";
                            $modelListSQL = "SELECT * FROM Model ORDER BY Name";
                            $modelListResult = mysql_query($modelListSQL);
                            while ($modelListRow = mysql_fetch_array($modelListResult)){
                                echo "<option value='" . $modelListRow['ID'] . "'>" . $modelListRow['Name'] . "</option>";
                            }
                            echo "</select>";
                        echo "</td></tr>";

                        // Project Material Selection
                        echo "<tr><td>";
                            echo "<label for='material'>material</label>";
                        echo "</td><td>";
                            echo "<select name='material' style='width: 250px;'>";
                            echo "<option value='-1' selected>SELECT</option>";
                            $materialListSQL = "SELECT * FROM Material ORDER BY Name";
                            $materialListResult = mysql_query($materialListSQL);
                            while ($materialListRow = mysql_fetch_array($materialListResult)){
                                echo "<option value='" . $materialListRow['ID'] . "'>" . $materialListRow['Name'] . "</option>";
                            }
                            echo "</select>";
                        echo "</td></tr>";

                        // Project Finish Selection
                        echo "<tr><td>";
                            echo "<label for='finish'>finish</label>";
                        echo "</td><td>";
                            echo "<select name='finish' style='width: 250px;'>";
                            echo "<option value='-1' selected>SELECT</option>";
                            $finishListSQL = "SELECT * FROM Finish ORDER BY Name";
                            $finishListResult = mysql_query($finishListSQL);
                            while ($finishListRow = mysql_fetch_array($finishListResult))
                            {
                                echo "<option value='" . $finishListRow['ID'] . "'>" . $finishListRow['Name'] . "</option>";
                            }
                            echo "</select>";
                        echo "</td></tr>";

                        // Project Craftsman Selection
                        echo "<tr><td>";
                            echo "<label for='craftsman'>craftsman</label>";
                        echo "</td><td>";
                            echo "<select name='craftsman' style='width: 250px;'>";
                            echo "<option value='-1' selected>SELECT</option>";
                            $craftsmanListSQL = "SELECT * FROM Craftsman ORDER BY FirstName";
                            $craftsmanListResult = mysql_query($craftsmanListSQL);
                            while ($craftsmanListRow = mysql_fetch_array($craftsmanListResult)){
                                echo "<option value='" . $craftsmanListRow['ID'] . "'>" . $craftsmanListRow['FirstName'] . " " . $craftsmanListRow['LastName'] . "</option>";
                            }
                            echo "</select>";
                        echo "</td></tr>";

                        //Project Description
                        echo "<tr><td>";
                            echo "<label for='description'>Description</label>";
                        echo "</td><td>";
                            echo "<input type='text' name='description' id='textArea' style='width:250px'>";
                        echo "</td></tr>";

                        // Project Selling Price
                        echo "<tr><td>";
                            echo "<label for='price'>Price</label>";
                        echo "</td><td>";
                            echo "<input id='price' name='price' type='number' style='width:150px'>";
                        echo "</td></tr>";

                        // Project Completion Date
                        echo "<tr><td>";
                            echo "<label for='date'>Finish Date</label>";
                        echo "</td><td>";
                            $dateArray = getdate();
                            $month = $dateArray[mon];
                            $day = $dateArray[mday];

                            if ($month < 10){
                                $month = '0' . $dateArray[mon];
                            }
                            if ($day < 10){
                                $day = '0' . $dateArray[mday];
                            }

                            $todaysDate = $dateArray[year] . '-' . $month . '-' . $day;
                            echo "<input type='date' name='date' value='" . $todaysDate . "' style='width:150px'>";
                        echo "</td></tr>";

                        // Buttons
                        echo "<tr><td align='center'>";
                            echo "<input type='button' name='Save' value='Save' onclick='javascript:validateAndSubmit(this.form);' style='width:100px'>";
                        echo "</td><td align='center'>";
                            echo "<input type='button' name='Cancel' value='Cancel' onclick='javascript:cancelEntry();' style='width:100px'>";
                        echo "</td></tr>";

                    echo "</table>";
                echo "</form>";
            echo "</div>";

            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). Also, instead of attaching function `onload` you should be placing the script, that you want to run when page has been loaded, right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: When testing are you getting any errors in the browser console?

Comment: terSKo: Thanks for the advice, I will look into that and start changing those over in the near future.

Comment: Aaran: unfortunately I have not found any errors when running it.  I'm using Chromium to do my development, but haven't found anything there.  I've also tested in FireFox and didn't find any errors.  I haven't tried IE yet because I'm developing in Ubuntu at the moment.

Comment: Try changing this: `onclick='javascript:viewDetails($modelID);'` to this: `onclick='viewDetails($modelID);'`. You really shouldn't be using pseudo control anyway, but `onclick='javascript:` makes no sense and could be troublesome.

Comment: If I paste your code into a test.php. ignore the PHP errors and make a link `<a onclick='viewDetails(45);'>test</a>`, and change `viewDetails ()` to `window.location.href='test.php?ModelID=' + modelId;` it works. What is `new url`?? A typo or how your code actually is?

Comment: David: new URL is just pseudo code. I'm actually using www.Google.com to test right now. Which php errors? Sorry, I'm a complete php newb.

Comment: Marcel: thanks for the advice, I just tried that with the same results.  I'm thinking that it has something to do with the form, so I'm going to remove that as a test to see if that helps. At least it will give me an idea of where to start looking.

Answer (score 2):

window.location.href may not trigger reload in some browsers and cases..
You should add a reload after

like this:

```
window.location.href = '/foo/bar/';
window.locaton.reload(true)
```

But, some browsers delay milliseconds to perform location.href set. In this cases the window.location.reload(true) may complete before this.

Therefore, add a timeout in reload:

```
window.location.href = '/foo/bar/';
setTimeout('window.locaton.reload(true)', 500);
```

works in all browsers for me

Comment: Gustavo: Thanks for the advice.  Unfortunately this does not seem to have resolved my problem as I have the same behavior occurring.  It really seems to love my main page and not want to let me transfer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning!  I found the cause of my problem this morning and have been able to resolve the issue.  The problem I was causing is because I am using the  tag (stylized by css) to display the information, with an onclick event to call my JS code to redirect.  Within the  tag I had the href='', thinking that the JS would override that functionality, it doesn't!

Removing the href='' from the  tag resolved the issue and allowed me to redirect to the new page.  A second solution is to use my php code to dynamically create the href link within the  tag.

```
echo "<li><a onclick='viewDetails($modelID);'>" . $modelRow[1] . "<small>in stock: <value>" . $rowAvailCount . "</value> sold: <value>" . $rowSoldCount . "</value></small></a></li>";
```

OR

```
echo "<li><a href='inventorydetails.php?ModelID=" . $modelID . "'>" . $modelRow[1] . "<small>in stock: <value>" . $rowAvailCount . "</value> sold: <value>" . $rowSoldCount . "</value></small></a></li>";
```

I think I will go with the second example for two reasons.  First, it provides the link icon when hovering (which I know I can add through css, but this is easier.  Second, less JS code.

I thank you for all your help in resolving this!